# Javascript : filter array of object remove all objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got a simple question, been hours on it and can't figuring out the solution. I got an array of object. I want to remove the object that has same values that a variable I pass.

My problem is that it removes all the objects, even those that are not similar to my variable.

Here is my code

```js
function appSelect(variable) {
    //we check if the object already exists in my array {id:x, value:y}
    const found = myArray.find(obj => {
        return (obj.id === variable.id && obj.value === variable.value);
    });
        
    if (found) { 
        //If find it, I want to remove it from my array

        const filtered = myArray.filter(obj => {
            return (obj.id !== variable.id && obj.value !== variable.value);
        })

    //Return empty array
}
```

I receive the value from a select form. For exemple I got `myArray = [{id: 1, value: 12},{id: 2, value: 12},{id: 5, value: 12}]` and `variable = {id: 2, value: 12}`

What I did wrong?

Comment: What if there are multiple elements in the array, whose `id` is different, but the value is the same as that of the `variable` you are passing?

Comment: That's the point. Isn't the && condition taking care of this ? In `obj.id !== variable.id && obj.value !== variable.value` I want to say that I want to return only object that have not same id AND not same value

Comment: can you share myArray content?

Comment: Please share a more complete [mcve] enough for us to reproduce any issues. What are the values of `myArray` and `variable`?

Comment: myArray = [{id: 1, value: 12},{id: 2, value: 12},{id: 5, value: 12}] and variable = {id: 2, value: 12}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is the code below:

```
return (obj.id !== variable.id && obj.value !== variable.value)
```

Which means if `id` or `value` is the same,then it will be filtered.

You can change it to

```
return !(obj.id === variable.id && obj.value === variable.value)
```

Full code:

```
function appSelect(variable) {
    //we check if the object already exists in my array {id:x, value:y}
    const found = myArray.find(obj => {
        return (obj.id === variable.id && obj.value === variable.value);
    });
        
    if (found) { 
        //If find it, I want to remove it from my array

        const filtered = myArray.filter(obj => {
            return !(obj.id === variable.id && obj.value === variable.value);
        })

    //Return empty array
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a failed [DeMorgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). You want the opposite of `obj.id === variable.id && obj.value === variable.value`, which is `!(obj.id === variable.id && obj.value === variable.value)` or `obj.id !== variable.id || obj.value !== variable.value` when DeMorgan's Law is applied.

```
const filtered = myArray.filter((obj) => {
  return obj.id !== variable.id || obj.value !== variable.value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if one of the value is different then it's not the same objet, note that the first found check is unnecessary

```js
function appSelect(variable, arr) {
    return arr.filter(obj => (obj.id !== variable.id || obj.value !== variable.value))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
const myArray = [
  { id: 1, value: 12 },
  { id: 2, value: 12 },
  { id: 5, value: 12 },
];

const variable = { id: 2, value: 12 };

function appSelect(variable) {
  //we check if the object already exists in my array {id:x, value:y}
  const found = myArray.find((obj) => {
    return obj.id === variable.id && obj.value === variable.value;
  });

  if (found) {
    //If find it, I want to remove it from my array
    const filtered = myArray.filter((obj) => {
      // if you found the object variable in your array then you return nothing
      if (obj.id === variable.id && obj.value === variable.value) {
        return;
      }

      // if the current object is not object variable then return it
      return obj;
    });
    return filtered;
  }

  //Return empty array
  return myArray;
}

console.log(appSelect(variable));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).